# 452 Sender address blocked by rate limit

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using javax.mail to send email. I need to send emails in a short time and this happened "com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 452 Sender address blocked by rate limit". How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You can't, unless you switch to another SMTP server.  The rate limit is imposed server side, not client side.

Comment: Not knowing which mail vender you are using, nor their API and at the risk of sounding flippant I would say your only option is to pay them more money for a better service.